# Rails : Can I use forms from the public/index.html file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Am currently using Rails 3.0 to develop my app.
How to handle a form in the `public/index.html` file which I'm planning to use as my Home page.
Usually a view's action buttons gets paired with the corresponding method of its controller.
But how to handle this in case the index file in public directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible, so long as the `form`'s `action` attribute is pointing at an action of a  Rails controller. However, it is *not* the norm in Rails to use a static HTML page to capture data. The norm is to use the MVC architecture of Rails.

I have to ask: Have you read the documentation provided on the Ruby on Rails website? Check out http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org and read the Getting Started section.

Now, I think you might be using public/index.html because you don't know how to use a controller to serve the root of your website. Here's a quick example of how to use a controller instead of public/index.html:

1. Create a controller (i.e., `home` via `rails g controller Home index`)
2. Modify `routes.rb` and add `root :to=>"home#index"`
3. Delete `public/index.html`

The above is actually in the Edge Guides, Getting Stated section. So again, I strongly recommend you read the documentation. It will honestly save you a lot of trouble.